# How to save string numbers in a numpy array

Tags: python, string, numpy, int, readline

I have a TXT file in this way:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

These zeros are str. I wanna to save this on a numpy array.
The dimension is 2000*784.

I have this so far:

```
file = open("train.txt", "r")
training_data = file.readlines()

#train1=np.zeros((2000,784))


line_counter = 0
for line in training_data:
    words = line.split()
    for counter in range(0, 785):
        a = int(words[counter])
        train[line_counter][counter] = a
    line_counter = line_counter + 1
```

The corresponding error is:

> index 784 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 784

from this line:

```
train[line_counter][counter] = a
```

It would be appreciated if any body help me.
Best

Comment: The index of the last element in your line is 783, not 784. Indexing in Python starts with 0. Use `for counter in range(len(words))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)? Default delimiter is any whitespace.

```
train = np.genfromtxt('train.txt')
```